# Web Platform Installer 5.0 missing Service Fabric 2

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, web-platform-installer

When attempting to install Service Fabric 2 from [Microsoft Website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/), I tried to follow the link **Install the Service Fabric runtime, SDK, and tools for Visual Studio 2015**, which downloads an .exe file that fires up a Web Platform Installer (version 5.0).

When executing (with admin permissions) it doesn't find Service Fabric 2
[image]

Even when I search, I just get Service Fabric 1.5.x, which was already replaced by the new release version.

**State of the computer**

- Windows 10, all updates applied to current
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 installed
- It does have Service Fabric 1.5.x installed currently, and it was working
- [image]

Looking in another machine with Service Fabric 2 already installed, the Installer is able to find normally as expected. And it bears the same configuration: Win 10, VS2015, just have more RAM.

Is there another way to install?

*Ps.: I verified and made sure that the installer file name downloaded from Microsoft website did not get changed.*

Comment: I had same problem when trying to install azure-powershell from WebPI from this [Microsoft Website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/). Exactly same error. Hopefully this is a temporary interruption.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, looks like their feed at https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9842185 is currently moved / getting redirected. Due to which , web platform installer is unable to get the latest list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the original posting, MS has seemingly corrected the endpoint reference the Web Platform Installer was looking for: **MS Azure Service Fabric SDK - 2.0.135 (VS2015)**